# Windows 7 Partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am trying to create the new drive from the c drive, I already part the disk. but I have one problem when I want to create a new simple volume.

After completion all steps I got this message :

> The operation you selected will
>   convert the selected basic disk to
>   dynamic disk. If you convert the disk
>   to dynamic, you will not be able to
>   start installed operating systems from
>   any volume on the disk (except the
>   current boot value). Are you sure you
>   want to continue?

After I click finish on box. Then I click Yes to continue, but then there another box appear saying:-

> Dynamic disks are not supported by
>   this operating system or server
>   configuration. Dynamic disks are not
>   supported on clusters

Which part I missing? and how to solve this?

Comment: Why dont you just create the partition and format it?

Comment: telll me why i got this message....

Comment: i have two drive c & d the d is recovery and when i click on c it does not show me the option of format......

Comment: Is that because you are on C currently? Why do you want to format c:?

Comment: k please tell me the solution, what i have to do.

Comment: I would figure out if the answer posted answers your question, then I would ask a separate question related to what you really want to do, not some intermediate step, and the problems that arise.

Comment: ok.........,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Sounds like you already have 4 primary partitions, which is the limit for Windows.

Please post a screenshot of disk management and I may have a possible workaround for you.

Answer (score 0):

You got the first message because you are creating two volumes from one disk. This has to be managed (in this case by LDM) thereby creating a dynamic disk. You then got the second error message because your OS does not really support LDM, and there is very little reason that it should as it has no real need for storage virtualization.